# Как обратиться к геттеру определенного модуля в vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, middleware

Пытаюсь создать приватный роутер с помощью middleware и Vue. Для этого мне необходима функция

```
export default function auth ({ next, store }){
  if(!store.getters.auth.isLogged){
    return next({
      name: 'login'
    })
  }
  
  return next()
}
```

которая будет отслеживать залогинен ли пользователь, и соответственно перенаправлять маршруты. Только вот `store is not defined`, потому что значение `isLogged` лежит не в общем глобальном файле index.js, а в отдельном модуле-файле auth.store.js, а в функции обращение идет к общему store.

Как сделать в этой функции обращение к store конкретного модуля?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Информации для ответа очень мало, Vuex в принципе на сколько я знаю не отдает ошибку `store is not defined`.

Из вашего кода можно лишь заметить что обращение к геттеру написано не правильно. `store.getters.auth.isLogged` должно быть либо `store.getters.isLogged`, если модуль не именованный, либо `store.getters["auth/isLogged"]` если модуль именованый.

Я так же подготовил минимальный воспроизводимый пример правильной конфигурации приложения, возможно он поможет Вам разобраться с вашей ошибкой самостоятельно.

[image: Edit https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1287093]

*Если данный ответ вам не поможет, дополните ваш вопрос предоставив больше информации.*

Comment: Разобралась,спасибо!